# How to include a regular expression in a custom validator using c#

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm using custom validators so I can style textboxes. However, I'm unsure how to validate an email address - possibly using a regex expression? Here's the code I'm trying to adapt:

```
protected void CustomValidatorBillEmail_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        bool is_valid = txtBillingEmail.Text != "";
        txtBillingEmail.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        args.IsValid = is_valid;
    }
```

Any help, as always, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In asp.net is there a function to validate an email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812159/in-asp-net-is-there-a-function-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: @Jacob Eggers Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
protected void CustomValidatorBillEmail_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
         @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
         @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";

        Regex regex = new Regex(strRegex);

        bool is_valid = false;

        if (regex.IsMatch(txtBillingEmail.Text))
        { 
            is_valid = true; 
        }

        txtBillingEmail.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        args.IsValid = is_valid;
    }
```

Can it be improved? Need to learn!!

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework comes with a RegEx class (System.Text.RegularExpressions) which you would then supply with a regular expression to verify the email there are 100's of versions on the net.